# Cordova window.open _self not working but _blank working

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using inAppBrowser plugin in my cordova app.

I want to load external url in webview.

Here is my code of `www/index.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
   var ref = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no'); //This is working

   var ref = window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self'); //This is not working
}

</script>
```

I don't know why this is happening.

I added inappbrowser plugin.

Comment: i tried out your code in device with android version 6. Both _self and _blank works the same way for me. I tried out in cordova version 6.0.0 and inappbrowser plugin versio 1.2.2  Not sure what versions you are using. Also not sure what you exactly mean by not working.

Comment: I am using cordova 6.0.0 and inappbrowser plugin 1.2.1 and i am running it in iphone simulator. when i use _blank it loads website which of that url and if i use _self nothing happen.. only blank screen

Comment: I tried out in iPhone 5s device with iOS version 9.2.1. Works fine for both _self and _blank. I guess you need to give it a try on device once as simulators and emulators may not be reliable all the time.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try `cordova.InAppBrowser.open()` intead of `window.open()`.